# Failed to configure a DataSource in Spring Boot with H2 in-memory database

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am developing a Spring Boot application with H2 as an embedded in-memory database.  I'm facing an issue while trying to access the H2 console. Whenever I navigate to http://localhost:8080/h2-console, it prompts me for a username and password.

**The console output:**

```
2023-08-03T19:41:47.901+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] c.e.a.AlbacamiereaApplication            : Starting AlbacamiereaApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 5176 (C:\albacamierea\target\classes started by Robert in C:\albacamierea)
2023-08-03T19:41:47.916+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] c.e.a.AlbacamiereaApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-03T19:41:50.102+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-08-03T19:41:50.167+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-08-03T19:41:51.805+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-08-03T19:41:51.809+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [2.0.3] using APR version [1.7.2].
2023-08-03T19:41:51.851+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023]
2023-08-03T19:41:51.891+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-08-03T19:41:51.892+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-08-03T19:41:52.247+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-08-03T19:41:52.248+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4149 ms
2023-08-03T19:41:52.757+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-08-03T19:41:53.629+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:d48ab7e7-383a-4245-846e-d273ef5237bd user=SA
2023-08-03T19:41:53.637+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-08-03T19:41:53.884+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-08-03T19:41:54.170+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.6.Final
2023-08-03T19:41:54.178+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-08-03T19:41:54.854+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-08-03T19:41:55.528+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-08-03T19:41:56.089+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-08-03T19:41:57.195+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-08-03T19:41:57.221+03:00  INFO 5176 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-08-03T19:41:57.358+03:00  WARN 5176 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-08-03T19:41:58.582+03:00  WARN 5176 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: dab22a6d-fca6-4e5d-9796-8f4d30c2c9b5
```

I have tried accessing the H2 console with a blank username and password, as well as with the default "SA" username and no password, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have to exclude the h2 route within the Spring Security Filter Chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have Spring Security enabled but not explicitly allowed the path to your H2 endpoint.

A possible SecurityFilterChain setup for H2 only (should be positioned in front of the other FilterChains via `@Order`annotation):

```java
@Bean
@Order(5)
// @Profile("development")
public SecurityFilterChain h2FilterChain(
        HttpSecurity http,
        @Value("${spring.h2.console.path:/h2-console}") String h2ConsolePath) throws Exception {

    return http
            .securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
                    /* https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12546#issuecomment-1382891839 */
                    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(h2ConsolePath + "/**")))

            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())

            /* The H2 console runs in a frameset. Thus, we need to set 'X-Frame-Options' from 'deny' to 'sameOrigin'. */
            .headers(header -> header.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))

            /* Otherwise login into H2 won't work. */
            .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)

            .build()
}
```

Make sure to set the h2-console value in the properties correctly.